# Python/Pandas: Want Different Times of Day to by Unique DateTimes in DataFrame Index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, indexing

I have a csv file `pruned_results.txt` that looks like this:

```
2018-08-01 08:41:08, Wait for OK to Measure
2018-08-01 09:02:26, Wait for OK to Measure
2018-08-01 10:49:06, Wait for OK to Measure
2018-08-01 14:19:16, Wait for OK to Measure
2018-08-01 21:46:23, Wait for OK to Measure
2018-08-02 01:11:06, Wait for OK to Measure
2018-08-02 02:47:11, Wait for OK to Measure
2018-08-02 04:05:41, Wait for OK to Measure
```

The first column I want to import as a DateTime index in a pandas DataFrame. The second column is the data, and I'm calling it `State`. I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("pruned_result.txt", header=None, index_col=0)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.columns = ['State']
df.index.names = ['Timestamp']
```

So far, so good. As it turns out, I actually have one or two rows with identical timestamps. These are not important for me to keep. So I want to drop the duplicates before pivoting on the `State` column. The problem I'm running into is that apparently, rows are considered duplicate if they have the same date. But I want them to be considered a duplicate only if they match all the way to the same second of the day. That is, the code

```
df.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
```

removes far too many rows (I end up with only six rows after this command!). How can I change this behavior so that I drop only duplicates-to-the-second?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that `drop_duplicates` is dropping based on the columns, which in this case is just `'State'`. You want to keep non-duplicated indices so you should instead use `pandas.Index.duplicated` to mask the original `DataFrame`

```
df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
```

Comment: What does `~` do?

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm. Thanks much!

Comment: It negates/flips the boolean values. `pd.Index.duplicated` returns `True` if the index is duplicated, and `False` if it is unique. But we want the opposite, so `~` accomplishes that, changing `True` to `False` and `False` to `True`